# get meeting organizer mail address EWS API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I would like to get the meeting organizer mail address with the EWS API. Currently I'm just getting the a few properties of my appointment item. I heard that you can set which properties you want to get. My code looks like that:

```
CalendarView cview = new CalendarView(start, end);
                    cview.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
                    FindItemsResults<Appointment> appResults = calenFolder.FindAppointments(cview);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and managed to populate the Organizer.Address property using this:

```
ExchangeService service = calenFolder.Service;
service.LoadPropertiesForItems(appResults, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
```

Comment: You can also just include AppointmentSchema.Organizer as PropertySet.FirstClassProperties includes a whole range of properties, which you may not need.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but since I found it, others may find it as well. And then, the solution is five years older than this question.

The solution is in fact simple and will be found quickly when trying to post this problem at the microsoft forums:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0403c00e-008d-4eb2-a061-45e60664573e/how-can-i-get-smtp-address-to-an-organizer-with-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Short summary:

The organizer field does not contain an SMTP Address when retrieved with ExchangeService.FindAppointments, but it does if retrieved with ExchangeService.BindToItems or Appointment.Bind.

Answer (score -1):

there is a property in the appointment item for that , which is Organizer.Address

so if you have appointment variable called *appointment* the following code retrieves the organizer address

```
Var address = appointment.Organizer.Address;
```

Try to use this code

```
var appointments = _service.FindAppointments(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new CalendarView(start,end));
foreach (var appointment in appointments)
{System.Diagnose.Writeline(appointment.Organizer.Address)}
```

Comment: Yes thats true. But this property is always null.

Comment: can you put more of your code, maybe you are not binding the appointments.

Comment: Do I have to bind to the appointments to get the extended properties? Sometimes I revice an "The specified object was not found in the store"-Exception. How can I avoid that?

Comment: I did not get your question , is it related to the original question ? or what ? You did you show more of your code. 

But about the extended properties. In the case if you want to pull the items you have already . like when you want to report the appointments in the calendar, then you do not have to bind .