# EWS Organizer field

Tags: exchangewebservices

I already found a similar problem at [get meeting organizer mail address EWS API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825359/get-meeting-organizer-mail-address-ews-api)

In short: I read a Meeting, made by some person in our organization and send to others from our organization.

It seems I can't find out the Organizer Mail Address (but Outlook can). All Invitees have the organizer in their appointment in the following way:

```
  <t:Organizer>
    <t:Mailbox>
      <t:Name>Elias Koch</t:Name>
      <t:MailboxType>OneOff</t:MailboxType>
    </t:Mailbox>
  </t:Organizer>
```

Is there any way, to find out WHICH Elias Koch it is? I have two in our AD and I can't distinguish who of them invited to the meeting, except that I can look into both Elias' mailboxes and check who of them has set

```
  <t:MyResponseType>Organizer</t:MyResponseType>
```

But I don't want to look into fifty Mailboxes to find out which John Smith has invited someone to a meeting. Outlook certainly doesn't!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple and can be found quickly by trying to post this problem at the microsoft forums:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0403c00e-008d-4eb2-a061-45e60664573e/how-can-i-get-smtp-address-to-an-organizer-with-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Short summary:

The organizer field does not contain an SMTP Address when retrieved with ExchangeService.FindAppointments, but it does if retrieved with ExchangeService.BindToItems or Appointment.Bind.